# Check if array key exists that matches regex

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

Is there a quick(er) way to check if an array key exists that matches a pattern? My goal is to use the value of a key that starts with "`song_`", regardless of how it ends.

currently I'm doing this:

```
foreach($result as $r){
   // $r = array("title"=>'abc', "song_5" => 'abc')
   $keys = array_keys($r);
   foreach($keys as $key){
       if (preg_match("/^song_/", $key) {
          echo "FOUND {$r[$key]}";
       }
   }           
}
```

Is there a way to to a preg_match across arrays, or is `foreach` through `array_keys` the most native way to do that?

Comment: how many elements do you typically have in `$r` ? and how many of them start with `song_` as the key?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about using [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php):

```
$keys = ['song_the_first', 'title', 'song_5'];
$matched = preg_grep('/^song_/', $keys);
# print_r($matched)
#
# Array
# (
#     [0] => song_the_first
#     [2] => song_5
# )
```